# PowerShell: Disable echo in Read-Host

Tags: powershell

Consider the following example:

```
Read-Host "Enter a value"
```

While this works fine, every time the user hits enter after entering a value, the same value is echoed on the next line. This is driving me nuts. There must be a way of remove this stupid echo?

Comment: Why are you reading a value but not doing anything with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the entered value into a variable

```
$value = Read-Host "Enter a value"
```

unless I pass the variable back out to host like in the following example

```
$value = Read-Host "Enter a value"
$value
```

it won't be echoed.

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me nuts!

Comment: You can use $null variable for dummy values

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell Core, you need to use -MaskInput as in:

```
$pwd_string = Read-Host "Enter a Password" -MaskInput
```

[Read-Host reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-7.2#example-3-mask-input-and-as-a-plaintext-string)

Answer (score 0):

On a PowerShell subprocess inside NodeJS, `Read-Host` didn't work for me. I had to do it this way:

```
$null = [Console]::ReadLine()
```