# Powershell: unexpected echo in read-host

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to write a simple text manipulation filter in powershell (5.1 on W10-64 bits). My goal is to use it as part of a pipeline in a batch (.bat), e.g.:

```
command1.exe | powershell "...my filter..." | command2.exe
```

I am facing a weird problem: "Read-Host" cmdlet always echoes its input. Example:

```
echo 1234 | powershell "$a=Read-Host"
```

produces

```
1234
```

(NOTE: see [PowerShell: Disable echo in Read-Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306905/powershell-disable-echo-in-read-host)).

How can I avoid this unexpected echo? Is there any alternate way to read STDIN in powershell?

NOTE2: I know I could do all the pipeline work inside powershell, but for many reason this doesn't fit my case. What I want is a "generic filter" suitable to be part of a pipeline in a ".bat". And, no, a temporary file to store intermediate data is not an option.

EDIT: as noted by "Compo", MS documentation says this about Read_Host:

> You cannot pipe input to this cmdlet

So there is no point in trying to make it work.

EDIT2: As explainded by "mklement0", "[Read_Host] does accept pipeline, i.e. stdin input from the outside, such as when provided to PowerShell's CLI". The real problem is that it is intended to simplify user input, not to give generic access to stdin.

The actual question is: Is there any alternate way to read STDIN in powershell?

Comment: Please explain what the [[tag:batch-file]] tag is for. Your question specifically states that you're "trying to write a simple text manipulation filter in powershell", and only that your goal is for this to be part of a `.bat` file pipeline. Where exactly have you entered the commands you've shown in your question?

Comment: I added the "batch-file" tag because my typical use case is a pipeline inside a batch file. The command in my example comes from a test in a console, but the same happens in a batch. (But perhaps I am missing the point, sorry).

Comment: …but what console?

Comment: BTW, if you take a look at the [Read-Host command information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-5.1), you'll clearly see that **it does not accept pipeline input**.

Comment: "You cannot pipe input to this cmdlet"... I see... (+1 for you). So, is there any alternate way to accomplish this? (BTW: "console" in my case is the plain cmd.exe prompt)

Comment: You could try using .NET, i.e. [[System.Diagnostics.Process\]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @Compo: That limitation applies to PowerShell-_internal_ use only. Outside pipeline / stdin input _is_ read by `Read-Host`, albeit only one line at a time, and invariably with echoing the input.

Comment: Why not do the whole thing in powershell?

Comment: @js2010 Because "the whole thing" is part of a legacy set of scripts which I would prefer not to rewrite from scratch. Also, I want to consider my filter as a building block by itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any alternate way to read STDIN in powershell?

That's already happening, you just need to know how to hook it - like [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#using-enumerators) the [`$input` automatic enumerator variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#input) for example:

```
C:\> echo "camelCase" |powershell -Command "$input |ForEach-Object ToUpper"
CAMELCASE
```

Since PowerShell and CMD use slightly different syntaxes and can be a bit of a pain to escape, I'd strongly recommend putting your filter(s) in script files and invoking those:

```
# myUpperCaseFilter.ps1
$input |ForEach-Object ToUpper
```

```
# script.bat
command1.exe |powershell -File path\to\myUpperCaseFilter.ps1 |command2.exe
```

Comment: That's what I was lloking for! (BTW, cmd.exe syntax is a pain, but in some cases I can't avoid using it)

Answer (score 3):

This answer complements [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66546409/45375), which shows the right way to handle *data* passed to the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) via the pipeline (stdin).

---

[`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host):

- Does ***not*** accept **pipeline input** from ***inside* a PowerShell session**, which is what the documentation refers to.
- ***Does*** accept pipeline, i.e. *stdin*<sup>[1]</sup> input **from the *outside***, such as when provided to PowerShell's CLI.

However, this comes with **limitations**:

- As in interactive use, **`Read-Host` only ever reads *one* line.**
- Because interactive behavior is emulated even with stdin input, the **input is *invariably echoed* to the display** as well, which cannot be suppressed.
- Unlike *all other* cmdlets (as well as expressions) - which require the explicit use of `$input` in order to process stdin data, as shown in Mathias' answer - `Read-Host` *implicitly* reads stdin input.

  - The implication is that **you must *either* consume stdin input entirely via `Read-Host` calls *or* use `$input` to relay it to other commands**.

---

This leaves **only *one* legitimate use case for piping strings to `Read-Host` *from outside PowerShell***:

- **Providing *automated responses* to a given command's / script's *interactive prompts***; e.g.:

  ```
  C:\>echo y | powershell -c "$response = Read-Host 'Continue (y/n)'; if ($response.Trim() -ne 'y') { exit 2 }; 'continuing...'"
  Continue (y/n): y
  continuing...
  ```
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53330644/45375) for more  information.

---

Conversely, this means that you shouldn't use `Read-Host` to collect stdin input in a variable, given that only *one* line is read and given the unwanted echoing behavior.

Typically, you simply relay stdin input by command-internally piping `$input` to other commands, as shown in Mathias' answer; **to explicitly collect all stdin input in a variable up front**, you can apply `$()`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) (or `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--)) to the `$input` enumerator:

```
C:\>(echo abc & echo def) | powershell "$allInput=$($input); \"$($allInput.Count) lines received.\""
2 lines received.
```

---

<sup>[1] *stdin*, the standard input stream, is an OS-level concept, as are the standard *output* streams, *stdout* and *stderr*. By contrast, **PowerShell implements its own system of streams**: the 6(!) *output* streams are described in the conceptual [`about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) topic; the *success* output stream (number `1`) and the *error* stream (`2`) are the analogs to *stdout* and *stderr*, respectively. However, there is no *stdin* analog as such: (stream) input to other commands is only ever provided *via the pipeline* (and not also via the `<` operator supported in other shells, which PowerShell does *not* support).</sup>